# Why functions.php doesnt work, blank page after reload

Tags: php, wordpress

after adding this to functions.php, i get an error (white page), i have the open tag php and a closing.

```
<?php

add_theme_support('menus');


function my-theme_add_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'google-map', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false', array(), '3', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'google-map-init', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/google-maps.js', array('google-map', 'jquery'), '0.1', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my-theme_add_scripts' );

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: Change `my-theme...` to `my_theme...`, you'll get a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ( ...` error.

Comment: rename your function my-theme_add_scripts to someone else....

Comment: Blank pages ALWAYS means **Syntax** error. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your file to see any possible error and show us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `function my_theme_add_scripts()` instead of `function my-theme_add_scripts()`. You can't use `-` in your function names.